# how to add up values from checkboxes in php

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

for training purposes i've made a little code which outputs the value of a checkbox. this works well, but since i am able to check multiple checkboxes i want them to add up. this is my code;

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>
<form name="orderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">


<input type="checkbox" name="korting" value=15 /> Student 15% <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="korting" value=10 /> Senior 10% <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="korting" value=5 /> Klant 5% <br>
```

To output the value ive written;

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["korting"]))
{
if($_POST["korting"]==15)
{
    echo ("15 procent korting");
}
else if ($_POST["korting"]==10)
{
    echo ("10 procent korting");
}
else if($_POST["korting"]==5)
{
    echo ("5 procent korting");
}
else if(isset($_POST["korting"]) && (isset($_POST["korting"])))
{
    if($_POST["korting"]==25)
{
    echo ("25 procent korting");
}
}
}


?>
```

As long as one checkbox is checked, everything works fine. as soon as is check more than one it only uses the last one. I've tried multiple thing like:

```
else if(isset($_POST["korting"]) && (isset($_POST["korting"]))
{
    echo ("25 procent korting");
}
```

and

```
else if($_POST["korting"=15] && $_POST["korting"]=10)
{
    echo ("25 procent korting");
}
```

both do not give an error on the page but also don't work. I know it's probably better to use completely different approach but for now this is how the book teaches me

Greetings,

Lennart

Comment: Try using different names for you checkbox inputs. You are using the same name and this is why as soon as more than one is checked it only uses the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an array. The checkboxes would look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="korting[]" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" name="korting[]" value="10" />
```

`$_POST['korting']` would then be an array of values, like this:

```
array(
  0 => 15,
  1 => 10
)
```

You can loop through them to print out the values:

```
foreach ($_POST['korting'] as $korting_value) {
  echo $korting_value . "<BR>";
}
```

If you want to add up the values, you can use array_sum:

`echo array_sum($_POST['korting']);`